# What is the different between the web server and CalDav server?

Tags: httpwebrequest, http-headers, webserver, caldav

I want to ask some basic knowledge of server.

1) What is the different between the web server and the CalDav server?

2) How to set the web server and CalDav server?

3) If I send a request to CalDav server ( I assume that I have the URL of the server), will the response header contains the data within the CalDav server (e.g. .vcf file)?

Can anyone help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you read wiki document? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CalDAV

Comment: @adatapost, thank you for your reply. I have read this document of the CalDav server, but I found that it does not contains the setting of the CalDav server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. CalDAV is basically specialized WebDAV, which is basically HTTP. I'd guess most CalDAV servers are normal web servers with some additional module or configuration.
2. Depends on your web server software. For Apache, there's [mod_caldav](http://sourceforge.net/projects/modcaldav/).
3. I'm not sure I really understand this question, but assuming you send valid CalDAV requests as per the [CalDAV specs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4791), you'd get well-formed CalDAV replies. I'm not too versed in the CalDAV protocol, but you can read up on it yourself.